# Как исправить код закрытия окон?

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать функцию с названием closeAllPopups что бы задействовала данный код ?

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27 && editPopup.classList.contains('popup_active')) {
        editPopup.classList.remove('popup_active');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 27 && addPopup.classList.contains('popup_active')) {
        addPopup.classList.remove('popup_active');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 27 && imagePopup.classList.contains('popup_active')) {
        imagePopup.classList.remove('popup_active');
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function closeAllPopups() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.popup_active').forEach(i => i.classList.remove('popup_active'));
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27)
    closeAllPopups();
}, true);
```