# Почему не работает код закрытия окон?

Tags: javascript

Нужно что бы все эти окна закрывались на клавишу esc. Цифровой код кнопки сделал константой , но работать не хочет

```js
const ESCAPE_KEY_CODE = 27;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
    if (evt.key == ESCAPE_KEY_CODE && addPopup.classList.contains('popup_active')) {
        togglePopup(addPopup);
    };
    if (evt.key == ESCAPE_KEY_CODE && editPopup.classList.contains('popup_active')) {
        togglePopup(editPopup);
    };
    if (evt.key == ESCAPE_KEY_CODE && imagePopup.classList.contains('popup_active')) {
        togglePopup(imagePopup);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте событие не на документ а на window

Comment: Дело совершенно не в этом.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас же уже был работающий код - [Как исправить код закрытия окон?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1162612/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd).

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
  console.log(typeof evt.key, evt.key, typeof evt.keyCode, evt.keyCode);
});
```

Comment: Заставили переделать
Обработчик нажатия на Escape, объявленный на window, следует добавлять при открытии и удалять при закрытии модального окна. При этом удобно будет функцию togglePopup разбить на две и туда вынести логику добавления и удаления слушателя keydown
Вместо того, чтобы проходиться по всем модальным окнам в цикле, лучше будет получить открытое модальное окно

Comment: Так в модальном окне откуда взяться документу?

Comment: Вставьте обработчик на событие на див в этом окне

Comment: понял, сейчас сделаю

Comment: @Иваниванов "Вместо того, чтобы проходиться по всем модальным окнам в цикле" - кто это предлагал?